# In-App purchase - does it possible to maintain group based products

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, cocoa

I have more than hundreds of products. We can split products by group. Each group can have different pricing tier. For example, group1 -> tier1, group2 -> tier2, group3 -> tier3, etc. All products in a group should be same pricing tier.

Is it possible to implement group based pricing tier? And also, i want to maintain the product status information (purchased or not).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can. It's a good idea as it would save a lot of time, but I think you have to manually change each one if your IAPs are already live.

If you're adding new items you can at least use a CSV file to upload them using Application Loader, which I suppose you could generate automatically based on your groups.